# Airflow - TriggerDagRunOperator - Call same DAG with different Conf

Tags: python, airflow

I've one dynamic DAG (dag_1) that is orchestrated by another DAG (dag_0) using TriggerDagRunOperator.

The dag_1 is a very simple script:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

default_args = {
  'provide_context': True,
}

def get_list(**context):
  p_list = ['a','b','c']
  res = context["dag_run"].conf['message']
  p_list.append(res)
  return p_list

with DAG(
  dag_id='dag_1',
  schedule_interval='@once',
  start_date=datetime(2022, 3, 1),
  default_args=default_args,
) as dag:
  data_list = PythonOperator(
    task_id='get_lists',
    python_callable=get_list,
    dag=dag)

  for i in get_list():
    bash_task = BashOperator(
      task_id='bash_task_{}'.format(i), 
      bash_command="echo 'command executed {}'.format(i)",
    )
```

And my dag_0 that will run orchestrate the dag_1 based on the parameters passed:

```
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator 
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG

dag = DAG(
  'dag_0',
  description='create the table structure',
  schedule_interval='@once',
  catchup=False,
  max_active_runs=1,
  start_date=datetime(2022, 3, 1),
)

trigger_step = TriggerDagRunOperator(
  task_id="trigger_step",
  trigger_dag_id="dag_1",
  conf={"message": "Hello Word 1"},
  dag=dag
)

trigger_step2 = TriggerDagRunOperator(
task_id="trigger_step2",
trigger_dag_id="dag_1",
conf={"message": "Hello Word 2"},
dag=dag,
)

 trigger_step >> trigger_step2
```

If I run this without the need to pass the PythonOperator to a list, it works fine by when I put that part `for i in get_list():` on first script I got:

```
res = context["dag_run"].conf['message'] KeyError: 'dag_run'
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've udated the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below. I think because that `dag_run` object is created at run time.

```
def get_list(dag_run=None,**context): 
    p_list = ['a','b','c'] 
    res = dag_run.conf.get('message') 
    p_list.append(res) 
    return p_list
```